# Rumor and probability

Tags: probability, statistics

31 people in a community, a person has a rumor to a second which, in turn, repeats to the third, etc. At each step the person receiving the rumor is randomly chosen among 30 people available.

a) Find the probability that the rumor is transmitted 15 times without going back to the first person you told?

b) Find the probability that the rumor is transmitted 15 times without it to be repeated to anyone.

Guys, I did not get this question. Could you help me to understand it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Basic approach.**  Let $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_{31}$ be the people in question.  $a_1$ starts the rumor, and tells a randomly selected person.  Then that second person tells a randomly selected person.  And so on.

(a) The first time the rumor is transmitted, of course, $a_1$ cannot tell $a_1$ themselves.  Thereafter, though, $a_1$ is avoided each time with probability $29/30$.  Thus, the probability that $a_1$ is avoided $14$ times in a row is ...?

(b) The first time the rumor is transmitted, again, $a_1$ cannot tell $a_1$ themselves.  The second time, though, the rumor must avoid one person ($a_1$ again), which it does with probability $29/30$.  The third time, the rumor must avoid two people ($a_1$ and the second person), which it does with probability $28/30$.  And so on.  Thus, the probability that the rumor passes $15$ times, through $16$ distinct people, is ...?

Comment: a=406/30 ? and b= I did not get it

Comment: Oh, no: When you have multiple independent events, and you want the probability of them all happening, you need to multiply the individual probabilities, not add them.  For instance, the probability that the second transmission avoids $a_1$ is $29/30$; the probability that the third transmission also avoids $a_1$ is also $29/30$.  The probability that they both do is $29/30 \times 29/30 = 841/900$.  But in this case, there are $14$ separate events that you must multiply together.

Comment: Remember, a probability must be a number between $0$ and $1$, so a probability of $406/30$ makes no sense.

Comment: So do I have to do 29/30 × 29/30 × 29/30 × 29/30 × 29/30 × 29/30 × 29/30 × 29/30 × 29/30 × 29/30 × 29/30 × 29/30 × 29/30 × 29/30?

Comment: about the second question, do I have to do 29/30 × 28/30 × 27/30 × 26/30 × 25/30 × 24/30 × 23/30 × 22/30 × 21/30 × 20/30 × 19/30 × 18/30 × 17/30 × 16/30× 15/30× 14/30?

Comment: First one is right. Second one has too many terms by two, at the end.

Comment: 29/30 × 28/30 × 27/30 × 26/30 × 25/30 × 24/30 × 23/30 × 22/30 × 21/30 × 20/30 × 19/30 × 18/30 × 17/30 × 16/30?

Comment: Yes, that's right.